# AJAX calling twice after first attempt

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a page inside a dialog like this:

```
foreach($resultados as $list) {
    $impreso = $list['entregado'];
    $pagado = $list['pagado'];

    if ($reimpresion != 1) {
        if ($pagado == 0 || $impreso != 0) {
            $classF = "";
            $classE = "";
            $titleF = "Pago Pendiente o ya fue impreso";
            $titleE = "Pago Pendiente o ya fue impreso";
            $disable = "disable";
        }
    }

    $style = "";


    ?>
<tr <?php echo $style; ?> >
    <td>
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $list['id']; ?>" />
        <span class="nro"></span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $list['urgente']; ?>
    </td>
    <td class="<?php echo $disable; ?>">
        <button class="<?php echo $classF; ?>" title="<?php echo $titleF; ?>" value="<?php echo $list['id']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-print"></i></button>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $list['folio']; ?>
        <div class="datt" id="<?php echo $list['folio'] ?>"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo date("d-m-Y",strtotime($list['fecha'])); ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $list['paciente']; ?>
    </td>
    <td class="<?php echo $disable; ?>">
        <button class="<?php echo $classE; ?>" title="<?php echo $titleE; ?>" value="<?php echo $list['ordenDetalleId']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-print"></i></button>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php  }?>
</table>
```

and a script like this

```
$(function() {
   $(".imprimirFolio").on("click", function() {
       var ordenId = $(this).parent().parent().find("td:eq(0) input:eq(0)").val();
       var url = 'index.php?r=OrdenResultado2/printFolio/ordenid/' + ordenId;
       var windowName = 'Reporte'; //window.open(url, windowName, 'height=900,width=800'); 
       $('#PDFREPORT').dialog({
           'modal': true,
           'title': windowName,
           'width': 700,
           'show': 'fade',
           'hide': 'fade',
           'height': 400,
           'open': function() {
               var pd = '<embed src="' + url + '" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%">';
               $('#PDFREPORT').html(pd);
           },
           close: function() {
               var fields = $("#buscador").find("form").serialize();
               var reimpresion = $("#reimpresion").val();
               $("#resultadosBuscador").load("index.php?r=ordenResultado2/BuscarResultados_Entrega/reimpresion/" + reimpresion + fields);
           }
       });
   });

   $(".imprimirExamen").on("click", function() {
       var ordenDetalleId = $(this).val();
       var url = 'index.php?r=OrdenResultado2/printExamen/ordenid/' + ordenDetalleId;
       var windowName = 'Reporte'; //window.open(url, windowName, 'height=900,width=800'); 
       $('#PDFREPORT').dialog({
           'modal': true,
           'title': windowName,
           'width': 700,
           'show': 'fade',
           'hide': 'fade',
           'height': 400,
           'open': function() {
               var pd = '<embed src="' + url + '" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%">';
               $('#PDFREPORT').html(pd);
           },
           close: function() {
               var fields = $("#buscador").find("form").serialize();
               var reimpresion = $("#reimpresion").val();
               $("#resultadosBuscador").load("index.php?r=ordenResultado2/BuscarResultados_Entrega/reimpresion/" + reimpresion + fields);
           }
       });
       event.stopImmediatePropagation();
       return false;
   });

   $('.nro').each(function(i) {
       $(this).html(i + 1);
   });
});
```

The first time I press on `.imprimirExamen` the code works great but the second time it calls the function twice. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: [How do I format my code blocks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Most of the time that means there is a binding issue, like you loaded something dynamically and the `click` method was registered twice so it runs twice every time you click.

Comment: Yes, buy i dont see how i could registered it twice. Could you please give me a hint?

Comment: Is any part of the page reloading at any time?  The most common thing I've seen is that part of the page is loading (typically the result of an ajax call) and the part that loads has the javascript on it.  If you find that, post the html and I'll show you how to fix the javascript for it.